Where is EF6.exe?
According to:
Source 1
Source 2
I should be able to find and extract ef6.exe by downloading Entity Framework from this site. After downloading, I am able to change entityframework.6.4.4.nupkg to entityframework.6.4.4.zip, and extract everything. I can then navigate to tools directory. However, I am not seeing ef6.exe:

None of the other folders has the executable. Am I missing something? If anyone can help me find ef6.exe, that would be very helpful.

The assembly is under the net45, etc folder.

